# Does Versatile Duelist allow sneak attacks without combat advantage?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

> Versatile Duelist
>
> Benefit: You gain proficiency with all one-handed, military heavy blades. If a rogue power
> requires you to wield a light blade, you can use that power with a one-handed heavy blade and can also deal your Sneak Attack damage while using a one-handed heavy blade with that power.

**Do you still need CA to deal Sneak Attack damage with this feat or does this automatically deal Sneak Attack damage?**

Answer (score 5):

**You need combat advantage.**

Versatile Duelist just allows you to sneak attack with a broadsword. It's not particularly interesting. The key way to read this is *can deal*. This is adding an exception to what types of weapons can be used.

*Note well*. This does *not* allow you to apply the rogue weapon talent to military heavy blades. Considering the benefits of light weapon expertise and nimble blade, it's generally better to go with a rapier than a longsword, especially as it's trivial to get rapier expertise via a background.

Comment: "rapier expertise via a background" Please elaborate where can I find this book or magazine wise.

Comment: Background: [Gritty Sergeant](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/background.aspx?id=49)